# Remove the sidebar in certain WooCommerce product category pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have code that removes the sidebar from WooCommerce pages.

```
add_action('body_class', 'my_remove_sidebar');
function my_remove_sidebar() {
    if (is_shop() || is_product_category( array( 'roset', 'plank' ) ) ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work for me. Can you suggest a more correct code?
How can I remove the sidebar from certain product category pages, if set their as an array?

p.s. I use the WOOF Products Filter plugin

Comment: Instead of using the action `body_class` have you tried another action, like `init` ?

Comment: Yes, everything is the same. I forgot to add that I use the WOOF Products Filter plugin. I updated the question.

Comment: It should definitely work, the `init` is a correct hook (just tested in on multiple stores). What theme are you using? I am guessing your theme might render the sidebar independently on the `woocommerce_sidebar` action, therefore it is being displayed despite of your `remove_action` call. I would check the theme templates (e.g. `archive-product.php`, etc.) to see HOW is the sidebar displayed. PS: The plugin shouldn't make a difference, because it is probably handling it's own widgets inside the sidebar, not the sidebar alone.

Comment: You are right, this code works. The problem is with the theme styles. Then I will create another question.